# UIContainerView with embedded UITableViewController has a grey background on Xcode 5 (SDK 7)

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios6, xamarin.ios, ios7

After migration from Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode 5 I had a lot of issue regarding the while UI stuff.

After compiling my application with SDK 7 (Deployment Target 6.1) my `UIContainerView`becomes grey. I've set the view background color of the container to white as well as the background color of the table view.

The old (original iOS 6 version had also a white background color)

Now it looks like this:
[image: iOS 6]

In iOS 7 it looks like expected:
[image: iOS 7]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

Setting the background color doesn't work at all.

For Xamarin.iOS / Monotouch
`TableView.BackgroundView = null;`

Objective-C
`[UITableView setBackgroundView: nil];`